# Testing Redux Toolkit Query returns empty collection - Provider issue (?)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, rtk-query

I have a `features/postsSlice` file:

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const postsSlice = createApi({
    // Reducer Path it's name shown on Redux Tab
    reducerPath: "postsSlice",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL,
    }),
    // With tag type we can invalidate cache
    tagTypes: ['posts'],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getPosts: builder.query({
            query: () => "/posts"
        })
    })
});

export const { useGetPostsQuery } = postsSlice;
```

I have a simple component to show posts got from `typicode`

```js
import React from "react"
import { useGetPostsQuery } from "../features/postsSlice"

export const GenericList = () => {

    const {
        data: posts,
    } = useGetPostsQuery();

    console.log(posts)

    if (posts && posts.length > 0) {
        return (
            posts.map(post => {
                return <p key={post.id}>{post.body}</p>
            })
        )
    }
    return <p>No data to shown</p>
}
```

And this is the `store/index.js` file:

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { setupListeners } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query";
import { postsSlice } from "../features/postsSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [postsSlice.reducerPath]: postsSlice.reducer
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(postsSlice.middleware),
})

setupListeners(store.dispatch);
```

It works. Now I want to test it with Jest and nwm.

This is the test file

```js
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { rest } from "msw";
import { setupServer } from "msw/node";
import { GenericList } from "../../components/GenericList";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "../../../src/store/index";

const server = setupServer(
  rest.get("https://api.example.com/api/posts", (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(
      ctx.json([
        {
          id: 1,
          body: "Foo",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          body: "Bar",
        },
      ])
    );
  })
);

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
afterAll(() => server.close());

describe("Test GenericList component", () => {
  test("Can render list of posts", () => {
    render(<Provider store={store}><GenericList /></Provider>)
  });
});
```

But in console I have `undefined` for that console.log.

```bash
 PASS  src/__tests__/components/GenericList.test.js
  ● Console

    console.log
      undefined

      at GenericList (src/components/GenericList.js:10:13)

    console.log
      undefined

      at GenericList (src/components/GenericList.js:10:13)

 PASS  src/__tests__/App.test.js
  ● Console

    console.log
      undefined

      at GenericList (src/components/GenericList.js:10:13)

    console.log
      undefined

      at GenericList (src/components/GenericList.js:10:13)
```

### Edit #1

I tried to remove completely the `mws` wrapper and let test calls real API. I have another time `undefined`. So, I'm wrong with the `<Provider>` implementation, my thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong.
Getting `undefined` here is totally normal while data is loading - and your test just renders the component and immediately looks at the result.
So of course at that moment, you are in a loading state.

You just didn't notice because you only looked at `data`.
Take a look at the other properties on that object and you will notice that you test a situation where either `isUninitialized` or `isLoading` are `true`.

Comment: Probably you are right. But I changed the approach, more "RTK-query" centric. Cause you are a mantainer, would you help me on my new question here? Thank you in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74447801/issue-testing-rtk-query-the-preloadedstate-argument-passed-to-createstore-has-u