# Issue testing RTK Query: The preloadedState argument passed to createStore has unexpected type of "array"

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm learning RTK Query.

So, in a test, I have the following error:

```bash
The preloadedState argument passed to createStore has unexpected type of "array". Expected argument to be an object with the following keys: "queries", "mutations", "provided", "subscriptions", "config"
```

This is my test:

```js
test("Can use preloadedState", () => {
    const initialPosts = [
      {
        id: 1,
        body: "Lorem ipsum",
      },
    ];

    // wrap component with custom render function
    renderWithProviders(<GenericList />, {
      preloadedState: {
        postsSlice: initialPosts,
      },
    });

    const loremIpsum = screen.getByText(/lorem ipsum/i);
    expect(loremIpsum).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

I have followed this tutorial https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#preparing-initial-test-state.

This is my test-utils.js file:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { setupStore } from '../../store/index'
import { setupListeners } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query'

export function renderWithProviders(
  ui,
  {
    preloadedState = {},
    // Automatically create a store instance if no store was passed in
    store = setupStore(preloadedState),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {

  setupListeners(store.dispatch);

  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
  }

  return { store, ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }) }
}
```

This is my store:

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { postsSlice } from "../features/postsSlice";



export const setupStore = preloadedState => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: {
      [postsSlice.reducerPath]: postsSlice.reducer,
    },
    preloadedState,
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
    immutableCheck: false,
    serializableCheck: false,
  }).concat(postsSlice.middleware),
  })
}
```

And finally this is the `postsSlice`

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const postsSlice = createApi({
    // Reducer Path it's name shown on Redux Tab
    reducerPath: "postsSlice",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL,
    }),
    // With tag type we can invalidate cache
    tagTypes: ['posts'],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getPosts: builder.query({
            query: () => "/posts"
        })
    })
});

export const { useGetPostsQuery } = postsSlice;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just make up some random contents for your `initialState`, it has to be exactly the structure of your Redux state. And for RTK Query, that is a very complex internal structure that you should probably not mock (it could change in another version!).

Honestly, to your last question, this is a step backwards - if you want to test RTK Query, test it with a normal Redux store and mock the api.
All you were missing was to wait in your test until the result was rendered.
Faking internal data structures means that your test will just test a very small part of what actually happens.

Comment: Thank you for your time. But, mocking an initialState is shown also in official documentation...

So, it isn't possibile to add a fake initialState?

Comment: Of course, but you cannot just cram anything into `initialState`. It has to have the exact same shape as your actual shape. Imagine you have a state that should be `{ user: { name: "foo" } }` and you just put `{ person: { lastName: "bar" } }` in there. How should your computer know the difference?

Comment: Generally though, something like `initialState` is probably better used in testing state that you manually control with a hand-written reducer. For something like RTKQ which manages state shape for you, going the "mock the api" approach is probably the better option.

Comment: I understand you. But... I'm putting the same shape of real object. See response of https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts and check against my fake items...

Comment: It is most definitely not the shape of your store! Open your Redux devtools browser extension or console.log your state in a real application. A RTK Query api slice has **tons** of metadata that you ignore here. It is a completely different shape.